# Azure Automation: Parallel Job Handling (start-job)

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to convert an Azure PowerShell script to an Azure Automation Runbook, but I've run into an issue when using the "start-job" command. After the inline scripts are called, the jobs fail shortly after starting. It seems to me that the parameters are not passing through properly.

Is there something I'm missing to properly pass parameters within Azure Automation?

The commands that are failing:

`$CreatevNetGateway = {
    param($vNetName)
    New-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName $vNetName -GatewayType DynamicRouting
}
<#Start the jobs#>
Start-Job $CreatevNetGateway -ArgumentList $vNetName1
Start-Job $CreatevNetGateway -ArgumentList $vNetName2
Wait-Job *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell Workflow, when you pass a value into an InlineScript block, you need to add $using to the front of the value. Ex:

```
workflow foo {
    $message = "hi"

    InlineScript {
        Write-Output -InputObject $using:message
    }
}
```

In addition, starting other jobs within the Azure Automation sandbox is not supported. It looks like you are trying to run two tasks in parallel and then do something only after both complete. PowerShell Workflow (the language / engine Azure Automation runbooks run on) has the parallel keyword that can be used for this:

```
workflow bar {
    parallel {
        New-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName $vNetName1 -GatewayType DynamicRouting
        New-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName $vNetName2 -GatewayType DynamicRouting
    }
    # do something that happens after both of those complete
}
```

Comment: The first option looks like I won't have the ability to pass the values as attributes when the script is called, so I'm not sure that will work. You're calling $using: from within the inline script. I may try calling three separate inline scripts though and putting the "wait" command at the end. 

I tried the second option, as that is *exactly* what I'm looking for, but Azure Automation bombs out, saying "parallel" is an "Unexpected keyword".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pass as attributes -- do you mean parameters? Ex you want the InlineScript to be a function and to take in the $message variable dynamically?

Comment: Also I just tested parallel in Azure Automation and it works. Are you sure you're not trying to call parallel within an InlineScript? InlineScript runs its contents as PowerShell, not PowerShell Workflow, so the parallel keyword will not work within an InlineScript, since it is only available in PowerShell Workflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$CreatevNetGateway = {
    New-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName $args[0] -GatewayType DynamicRouting
}
<#Start the jobs#>
Start-Job $CreatevNetGateway -ArgumentList @($vNetName1)
Start-Job $CreatevNetGateway -ArgumentList @($vNetName2)
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The argument was never passed.